# Need imagebutton clear before Animation commences

Tags: android, animation, scale

So I start my activity and then

```
setContentView(R.layout.myxmllayoutfile);
```

All is well, but I want to make my imagebutton suddenly grow (scale) from nothing (ie 1%). However the layout is already displaying the button so it suddenly disappears then grows back rather than growing from nothing.

I have some alternatives but is there a real solution?:
1. flying the imagebutton animate in from offscreen? ; or
2.  making it tiny in the xml and then growing it, then if necessary changing the clickable area?; or
3.  is there a better solution?

UPDATE:
As suggested I tried:

```
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/spinner"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:layout_width="120dp"
android:layout_height="120dp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:background="@drawable/clear"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:visibility="invisible"
android:src="@drawable/spin" 
/>
```

and in my java:

```
scaleView.startAnimation(scanimation);
ImageButton spinnerbutton=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
spinnerbutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

but it is still visible before it shrinks to 1% then grows! Suggestions welcome.

UPDATE2:

Nothing has changed with the edited below code:

```
public void growit() {
final ImageView scaleView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
Animation scanimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.throbbing2);
scanimation.setFillAfter(true);
scanimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
public void onAnimationStart(Animation a) { Log.e("growit", "---- animation start listener called");
scaleView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation a) {
}
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation a) {
}
});
scaleView.startAnimation(scanimation);


}
```

Comment: Hide imagebutton in xml code.
Add android:visibility="gone" or "invisible" if it is appropriate in your case

Comment: android:visibility="invisible" already. I will try gone because I have nothing to lose.

Answer (score 1):

**Make imagebutton hidden.** 
Then in your animation set Animation listener and on start animation callback method set the button visible

UPDATE:

```
        Animation animation = new ScaleAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); 
        animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                mImageButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) { }
        });
        mImageButton.startAnimation(animation);
```

Comment: see example in UPDATE section

Comment: are you sure imagebutton is initially hidden? According to your code it is visible.

Comment: I tried making it invisible in the layout XML and then visible at the start (and failing that the end instead) of the animation but nothing has solved this issue, as yet.

Answer (score 0):

No permanent solution. Just used a workaround of making it tiny in the xml and then growing it as suggested in the question as a possible "solution"/workaround but not ideal.